# Bitwise operators in node.js with big numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, xor

Trying to get a xor of two big numbers, the result is not correct.

example:

```
 >  7894237947293^4353453453
105105424
```

while on python, for example, it gets the correct answer:

```
>>> 7894237947293^4353453453
7898549962768
```

How can I made a xor on node.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bignum lib https://github.com/justmoon/node-bignum

```
var bignum = require('bignum');

var b = bignum('7894237947293').xor('4353453453');
```

Answer (score 3):

bitwise operators in javascript implicitly cast numbers to int32, that's it. You need some sort of a 3rd party lib for that... or

Here is a way to do that:

```
var num1 = 7894237947293;
var num2 = 4353453453;

var r = 0;
var i = 1;

while (num1 > 0 || num2 > 0) {
  var a = num1 % 0x100000000;
  var b = num2 % 0x100000000;


  var c = a ^ b;


  r = r + i * c;

  i *= 0x100000000;

  num1 = Math.floor(num1 / 0x100000000);
  num2 = Math.floor(num2 / 0x100000000);
}

console.log(r)
```

but it will probably fail on same edge cases

Answer (score 1):

The [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) module works:

```
var bigInt = require("big-integer");

let result = bigInt('7894237947293').xor('4353453453');

// gives Integer { value: 7898549962768n }
```