# Bitwise operations on large numbers

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

This works as expected:

```
> 0b1111
15
> 0b1111 & 0b1111
15
```

But this doesn't:

```
> 0b11111111111111111111111111111111
4294967295
> 0b11111111111111111111111111111111 & 0b11111111111111111111111111111111
-1
```

What's going on here? And how can I safely perform bitwise operations on large (up to 2^32) numbers in Javascript?

**Update:** This is below `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` so I don't believe there should be a loss of precision.

Comment: What about [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) ? Or [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) library for managing unlimited integers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915045/bitwise-operators-in-node-js-with-big-numbers

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, that is a wrong dupe reference. This is not about floating point.

Comment: @trincot what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915045/bitwise-operators-in-node-js-with-big-numbers

Comment: I don't think so, as that deals with numbers with more than 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going on here?

JavaScript's bitwise operators will interpret the result as  a **signed** 32-bit number (one exception is the `>>>` operator), but apart from that, the result is correct.

> And how can I safely perform bitwise operations on large (up to 2^32) numbers in Javascript?

Apply `>>> 0` to the result so the result is interpreted as an **unsigned** 32 bit number:

```js
let res = (0b11111111111111111111111111111111 
            & 0b11111111111111111111111111111111) >>> 0;

console.log(res);
```